# How do I use findOrCreateEach in waterline/sailsjs?

Tags: sails.js, models, waterline

I been looking around on the sails site and was lead to the waterline page. I am curious to how I can use the `findOrCreateEach` method. Specifically, number of arguments, what it will return, and how it will benefit me using it? I been searching, around and going to have to dive into the source code. I figure I ask here while I look.

**Method without bluebird promises**

```
Model.findOrCreateEach(/* What Goes Here */).exec(/* What Returns Here */);
```

**With bluebird promises**

```
Model.findOrCreateEach(/* What Goes Here */).then(/* What Returns Here */);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`findOrCreateEach` is deprecated; that's why it's [not in the documentation](http://sailsjs.org/#/documentation/reference/waterline/models).  The best way to replicate the functionality is by using [.findOrCreate()](http://sailsjs.org/#/documentation/reference/waterline/models/findOrCreate.html) in an asynchronous loop, for example with `async.map`:

```
// Example: find or create users with certain names
var names = ["scott", "mike", "cody"];
async.map(names, function(name, cb) {
    // If there is a user with the specified name, return it,
    // otherwise create one
    User.findOrCreate({name: name}, {name: name}).exec(cb);
}, 
function done(err, users) {
    if (err) { <handle error and return> }
    <users now contains User instances with the specified names>       
});
```

Comment: Ahh I found it on the waterline docs. That's why I was curious about it. Makes sense why it is deprecated. Is there a CreateOrUpdate option?

Comment: what about createEach? I need to bulk insert list of records

Comment: Would your code return an array of records? Would this work? `const users = await async.map(names, ...);`